# is there collection type similar to dictionary, but allow the duplicated key in swift?

Tags: swift

I'm looking for a collection type in Swift, similar to dictionary, that can add duplicate keys. Something like:

```
var a = ["email": "a@xx.xxx", "email": "b@xx.xxx", "email": "c@xx.xxx"]
```

I need to send a POST request with payload to make a search request. 
Does it exist in Swift?

Comment: A [DictionaryLiteral](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionaryliteral) can have duplicate keys, but must be a literal; you cannot set the values dynamically. If you can't change the api to work more sensibly then you will need to write code to hand craft the Payload.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to duplicate a key in `Dictionary` neither in `Swift` not in `Objective-C`. To save multiple values against a same key you should use `Array` something like this.

```
{
   "email": [
     "xx1@gmail.com",
     "xx2@gmail.com",
     "xx3@gmail.com"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Even in any language I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Array of Tuple like this:

```
var email = [(String, String)]()
email.append(("email", "a@xx.xxx"))
email.append(("email", "b@xx.xxx"))
email.append(("email", "c@xx.xxx"))
print(email[2].1)
```

> c@xx.xxx

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `DictionaryLiteral` as:

```
let a: DictionaryLiteral = ["email": "a@xx.xxx",
                            "email": "b@xx.xxx",
                            "email": "c@xx.xxx"]
```